# How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?

Tags: fonts

The standard font packages make global changes to the fonts in my document. What if I want to use a particular font for just a portion of my text?

1. How do I find the right name of the font?
2. How do I select the font?
3. How do I restrict the scope of the font change?

---

There are separate answers for different flavors of TeX (quick links):

- [Regular LaTeX (including pdfLaTeX)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25251/)
- [XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37251/)
- [ConTeXt MkIV](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51650/)
- [Plain TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/214760/)

Comment: For short inline sections of font change, also discussed here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100575/how-can-i-temporarily-type-a-text-with-different-font-that-defined-in-the-style

Comment: @Alan I think we can remove the “small section” part of this question since it covers all application scopes?

Comment: @doncherry I think the intended scope of the question is about non-global font changes.

Comment: @AlanMunn I agree, but the scope of this question could easily be widened to include local and global changes, making it more canonical? Having a separate question for global changes seems like a waste of resources. The XeLaTeX answer is ready already, the pdfLaTeX and ConTeXt answers might need a bit of tweaking.

Comment: @doncherry: The global change is trivial when it just involves including a package. Making that change only for a portion of the document is, however, unexpectedly challenging (and I fear that's one more reason for non-LaTeX-people to refuse LaTeX), and I suspect a significant portion of the 200+ upvoters so far came here specifically looking for a way to *not* make a global font change, as I just did. Widening the scope of the question to include global changes could make it less obvious that the question actually explains how to locally apply a font.

Answer (score 477):

## Regular LaTeX

### Finding the font name

This is actually the hardest part. When you load a regular font package like `helvet` (which sets the default sans serif font to a Helvetica clone) it issues commands to set up the font using an internal name ([Berry name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23592)), which is hidden to regular users. These names traditionally use a system of three or four letter lower case names for each font family. Usually these names are documented in documentation associated with the font.

Here is a list of the most common fonts, and their codes:

```
Family                 Font Name
pag                    Avant Garde
fvs                    Bitstream Vera Sans
pbk                    Bookman
bch                    Charter
ccr                    Computer Concrete
cmr                    Computer Modern
pcr                    Courier
ugm                    Garamond
phv                    Helvetica
fi4 (zi4)              Inconsolata
lmr                    Latin Modern
lmss                   Latin Modern Sans
lmtt                   Latin Modern Typewriter
LinuxBiolinumT-OsF     Linux Biolinum (formerly 'fxb' in older package versions)
LinuxLibertineT-OsF    Linux Libertine (formerly 'fxl' in older package versions)
pnc                    New Century Schoolbook
ppl                    Palatino
qag                    TeX Gyre Adventor 
qbk                    TeX Gyre Bonum 
qzc                    TeX Gyre Chorus
qcr                    TeX Gyre Cursor
qhv                    TeX Gyre Heros
qpl                    TeX Gyre Pagella 
qcs                    TeX Gyre Schola
qtm                    TeX Gyre Termes
ptm                    Times
uncl                   Uncial
put                    Utopia
pzc                    Zapf Chancery
```

For some Greek fonts the codes are:

```
Artemisia              artemisia 
Baskerville            gfsbaskerville 
Bodoni                 bodoni 
Complutum              complutum 
Didot                  udidot 
Neohellenic            neohellenic 
Porson                 porson 
Solomos                solomos 
Greek Times            txr 
Kerkis                 mak 
LX                     llcmss 
Default                lmr
```

For others you can look at the fontname.pdf file [here](https://www.tug.org/fontname/fontname.pdf) on page 4.
See also the questions [Berry naming scheme list of LaTeX font families](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23592)
and [Quickest way to search for valid \fontfamily arguments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118969)
on this topic.

If you don't find any documentation for the font, as a last resort (or a first resort once you know what you are doing) you can open the `.sty` file that actually loads the font and see for yourself what the internal font family name is (or you could search inside it with `grep`).  Here are two examples:

From `helvet.sty`: at the end of the package is the line:

```
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
```

This sets the default sans font (`\sfdefault`) to the `phv` family, so `phv` is the internal name of the font.

From `PTSansCaption.sty`, you will find the following line:

```
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{PTSansCaption-TLF}
```

Here, the internal name is closer to its file name: `PTSansCaption-TLF`.

Both of these examples have shown the code for changing the default sans serif font. If the font package changes the roman or mono font you would look for the following commands respectively

```
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{...}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{...}
```

### Selecting the font

To select a font, you use the following commands:

```
\fontfamily{<familyname>}\selectfont
```

It's often useful to wrap this in a macro:

```
\newcommand*{\myfont}{\fontfamily{<familyname>}\selectfont}
```

### Restricting the scope of the selection

You can always restrict the scope of font changing commands by enclosing the text in braces:

```
{\fontfamily{<familyname>}\selectfont ...}
```

or if using a command

```
{\myfont ...}
```

or, to make the scope of the command more visible in your file if you don't have a brace-matching editor

```
\begingroup
  \myfont ...
\endgroup
```

If this is something you will be doing a lot, it would make more sense to turn it into a proper environment:

```
\newenvironment{myfont}{\fontfamily{<familyname>}\selectfont}{\par}
```

Then you use it like any other environment:

```
\begin{myfont}
  Some text in the new font.
\end{myfont}
```

You can also define a command corresponding to the standard font changing commands such as `\textrm` or `\textsf`, but using your particular font:

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textmyfont}{\myfont}
```

Use this like the standard commands:

```
Text in the default font. \textmyfont{Text in the new font.} Again text in the default font.
```

An advantage of this command over the simpler version described above is automatic italic correction, cf. [Why use \DeclareTextFontCommand vs. just \newcommand?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47259).

---

### Common fonts rendered

(except *ccr Compute Concrete*).

[image: Common fonts]

Comment: Wow, huge thanks to whoever took my meagre beginning of an answer and made it 100 times better.

Comment: What's the recommended way of limiting the scope of the font to *just* the block? The calligra font (http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/calligra/) seems to have a `\calligra` command that applies only to the current block, however for some packages (like http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/tgchorus/) set the default font for the entire document. Must one reset this (using `\renewcommand`) right after the `\usepackage` command and _then_ use the \myfont macro you describe?

Comment: visual reference: [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/), for example here the [Typewriter Fonts](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/typewriterfonts.html)

Comment: @Alan Munn When using `\newcommand*{\myfont}{\fontfamily{<familyname>}\selectfont}` or `\newenvironment{myfont}{\fontfamily{<familyname>}\selectfont}{\par}` and then in the text `begin`/`end`, the text does not get justified and it exceeds the set width of the text. Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: @Valerio Make a minimal example document that shows the problem and then ask a new question.

Comment: @Alan Munn Done it. Please see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/370267/105858)

Comment: You explained expertly how to find the font's name (namely, by looking inside the `.sty` file). Is there a similar way to find the font's encoding? Also, you mentioned the font's documentation. Where would I find the documentation associated with a given font?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. A minor correction: for `Inconsolata`, the correct font name is `zi4` instead of `fi4`. Also, following @EvanAad question: how can we proceed when the font package contains no `.sty` files at all?

Comment: Wow finding the font family name really was the hardest part haha

Answer (score 264):

### XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

The appearance of  XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX has simplified font selection greatly for LaTeX users, since any font installed on your system can be used with these engines using the `fontspec` package to load the font.

Both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX assume by default UTF-8 input, so you should *not* load the `inputenc` package when using them, and you should save your source files as UTF-8.

A basic document will therefore look like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{<any font on your system>}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

**Selecting fonts globally**

For a whole document, you can set the roman font, the sans serif font and the monospace font with the following commands:

```
\setmainfont[<font features>]{<name of font>} % sets the roman font
\setsansfont[<font features>]{<name of font>} % sets the sans font
\setmonofont[<font features>]{<name of font>} % sets the monospace font
```

**Selecting fonts locally**

If you want to use a font for a small section of your document it's best to define a new *font family*.

```
\newfontfamily\myfont[<font features>]{<name of font>}
```

This sets up a switch called `\myfont` which changes the font to that font.
(It is also possible to select a font directly using the `\fontspec` command, but this is generally to be avoided, since the `\newfontfamily` method is much more efficient.)  This switch behaves exactly like `\rmfamily` or `sffamily` (except that it is called `\myfont` and switches to the font assigned to it).

**Font Features**

Since `fontspec` package provides access to OpenType fonts, it is able to provide access to many of the special features that come with these fonts.  These features can be selected using the optional argument of any font selection command.  See the `fontspec` documentation for more details.  I'll outline a couple of commonly used features here.

- `[Ligatures=TeX]` This feature allows you to use regular TeX ligatures (which are not turned on by default in `fontspec`. Especially if you are used to e.g. typing LaTeX style quotation marks or `--` and `---` instead of typing the actual characters directly, you should always turn on this option.
- `[Numbers=OldStyle]` This feature turns on lower case numbers
- `[Scale=MatchLowercase]` This feature is used to scale e.g. the sans or mono font to match (in this example) the lower case characters of the roman font.  Another option is `MatchUppercase`; alternatively a numeric scaling value can be given.

See the `fontspec` documentation for a full description of the wealth of features that can be specified.

If you are setting separate roman, mono, and sans fonts or creating new font families, you often want to have the same font features specified for all.  You can do this by using the `\defaultfontfeatures` command:

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX} % makes this a feature for all selected fonts
```

### Finding the name of the font

If you are using system fonts, you can use the name of the font as it appears in any GUI application on your system. (On a Mac, these are usually the fonts in `/Library/Fonts`; on Windows they are usually in `\Windows\Fonts`; on Linux the usual place is `/usr/local/share/fonts`.  For example:

```
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\myfont{Linux Libertine O}
```

There's really no sense in listing font names here, but I'll add some examples of what the names can look like:

- Arial Rounded MT Bold
- DejaVu Sans Mono
- Florencesans SC Black

These names are *not* the filenames of the fonts. If you have some sort of font manager GUI like Font Book on the Mac, the names are displayed there. On Windows you can find the names in the Fonts preview section of the control panel.

Notice that spaces that normally appear in the name of the font must also be present when you choose the font using `fontspec`.

If you want to list the fonts which support a certain language (since fonts usually support only part of the Unicode character), you can use the `fc-list` command. For example, to find fonts which support Chinese, first find the [language code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) of Chinese, i.e., `zh`, then we use the following command

```
fc-list :lang=zh
```

to show the list of fonts supporting Chinese. Output will be something like:

```
/usr/share/fonts/custom/STLITI.TTF: STLiti,华文隶书:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/custom/SourceHanSerifSC-Regular.otf: Source Han Serif SC,思源宋体:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/wqy-microhei/wqy-microhei.ttc: WenQuanYi Micro Hei Mono,文泉驛等寬微米黑,文泉驿等宽微米黑:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/custom/simhei.ttf: SimHei,黑体:style=Regular,Normal,obyčejné,Standard,Κανονικά,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Standaard,Normalny,Обычный,Normálne,Navadno,Arrunta
/usr/share/fonts/custom/SIMLI.TTF: LiSu,隶书:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/custom/STXINWEI.TTF: STXinwei,华文新魏:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/wqy-zenhei/wqy-zenhei.ttc: WenQuanYi Zen Hei Sharp,文泉驛點陣正黑,文泉驿点阵正黑:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/custom/simfang.ttf: FangSong,仿宋:style=Regular,Normal,obyčejné,Standard,Κανονικά,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Standaard,Normalny,Обычный,Normálne,Navadno,Arrunta
/usr/share/fonts/wqy-microhei/wqy-microhei.ttc: WenQuanYi Micro Hei,文泉驛微米黑,文泉驿微米黑:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/custom/FZYTK.TTF: FZYaoTi,方正姚体:style=Regular
```

The font name is after the font location, for example, `STLiti`.

### Restricting the scope of the selection

You can always restrict the scope of font changing commands by enclosing the text in braces:

```
{\myfont ...}
```

or, to make the scope of the command more visible in your file if you don't have a brace-matching editor

```
\begingroup
  \myfont ...
\endgroup
```

If this is something you will be doing a lot, it would make more sense to turn it into a proper environment:

```
\newenvironment{myfont}{\myfont}{\par}
```

Then you use it like any other environment:

```
\begin{myfont}
  Some text in the new font.
\end{myfont}
```

You can also define a command corresponding to the standard font changing commands such as `\textrm` or `\textsf`, but using your particular font:

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textmyfont}{\myfont}
```

Use this like the standard commands:

```
Text in the default font. \textmyfont{Text in the new font.} Again text in the default font.
```

An advantage of this command over the simpler version described above is automatic italic correction, cf. [Why use \DeclareTextFontCommand vs. just \newcommand?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47259).

Comment: More font features: `[Color=000099]` (dark blue)

Comment: In the final section *Restricting the scope of the selection* I don't understand what 'myfont' is supposed to stand for. The font's name?? So if the font's name is, say, 'Linux Libertine O', is this how one switches to this font locally: `{\Linux Libertine O ...}`?

Comment: Another point of confusion for me is the following. The section *Finding the name of the font* begins with the following instruction 'If you are using system fonts, you can use the name of the font as it appears in any application on your system. (On a Mac, these are usually the fonts in /Library/Fonts[...]'. The filenames appearing in /Library/Fonts are *not* necessarily the names of the fonts, as there need be no relation between the name of a font's file and the font's name. So which name are you referring to? File or font? In the latter case, how can it be found on Mac, Windows and Linux?

Comment: @EvanAad `\myfont` is the literally the macro that is created when you use `\newfontfamily\myfont{Name of Font}`.  It is not the name of the font, but whatever name you choose to use as the macro to switch to that font. As for finding the names of fonts, on a Mac it is the name displayed in Font Book (or in the Font menu of any Mac application.) Similarly on other OSes, it is the name that is used in GUI applications, not the font filename.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Thanks. You wrote: "As for finding the names of fonts, on a Mac it is the name displayed in Font Book (or in the Font menu of any Mac application.)" It should be noted that, at the present time, LuaTeX exhibits a couple quirks (bugs?) on macOS that render it not 100% compatible with your statement, as follows.

Comment: @AlanMunn: . (1) Some fonts that are listed in Font Book as well as in, say, MS Word for Mac, such as the fonts of the `Avenir` family, are, by default, physically stored in `/System/Library/Fonts` rather than in `/Library/Fonts`. However LuaTeX does not search this folder by default. XeTeX does not have this issue. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/374294/21685).

Comment: @AlanMunn: (2) The `DFont` format is not supported in recent versions of LuaTeX, which excludes some fonts, such as `Courier`, that are listed in Font Book as well as in, say, MS Word for Mac. Again, XeTeX does not have this issue. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/374292/21685)

Comment: @EvanAad Yes, I'm aware of both of these issues. But I think that adding too many provisos to this answer clutters it up. (And your links will remain in the comments.) BTW DFonts can easily be converted into formats that LuaTeX can use.

Comment: @AlanMunn Quick question: I have defined a font family as described (*\newfontfamily\myfont{Linux Libertine O}*), and I can use *\begin{myfont}*...*\end{myfont}* without defining *\newenvironment{myfont}{\myfont}{\par}*.
If I define this environment like in the answer, I get a compilation error (\myfont already defined). I can, however, use a different name for the new environment and use that: then it works, but the only difference from not having it defined is that the text in question gets shifted sideways about 2 mm.

Comment: @Philipp The font commands are *switches* not environments. But the way LaTeX defines new commands allows them to be used as environments too, although this isn't really the recommended way. See [Are \end.... macro names reserved in LaTeX2e?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/199692)  Are you sure the shift you're seeing isn't just the regular paragraph indent?

Comment: @AlanMunn That explains why it works. I’ll define environments from now on instead of using the defined font switches as pseudo environments if that’s the recommended way. No, I’m not sure about the indent, but it’s very likely caused by the \par. Thanks for your reply, I didn‘t want to write a new question for that.

Comment: @Philipp But you need the `\par` in the environment, because it's only at the ends of paragraphs that TeX applies the changes.

Comment: I know, comments are not the place for this, but thank you so much for forcing me to finally read how fontspec with lualatex works instead of copying&pasting lazily. I'm starting to be fascinated by using different fonts in my works.

Answer (score 57):

## ConTeXt MkIV

In ConTeXt MkIV it is easy to use a font for a small
section. For larger parts of text I would recommend to use
the [Simplefonts
module](http://modules.contextgarden.net/simplefonts) or
to write typescripts, because larger parts probably contain
font switches that change the style.

### How do I find the right name of the font?

First you have to install the font, if
not already done. On Unix you can use the directory `$HOME/.fonts`
for a per user or e.g. `/usr/local/share/fonts` for a system wide
installation. You have to point the environment variable `OSFONTDIR` to the
directory where the fonts can be found:

```
export OSFONTDIR="/usr/local/share/fonts;$HOME/.fonts"
```

Then run

```
mtxrun --script fonts --reload
```

to regenerate the font database. Now you can query the database. This gives
you a list of all available fonts:

```
mtxrun --script fonts --list --all
```

Here are the first ten lines of this list:

```
ams                   wncysc10              wncysc10.afm
amsbold               wncyb10               wncyb10.afm
amsmedium             wncysc10              wncysc10.afm
antpoltbold           antpoltbold           antpolt-bold.otf
antpoltbolditalic     antpoltbolditalic     antpolt-bolditalic.otf
antpoltcondbold       antpoltcondbold       antpoltcond-bold.otf
antpoltcondbolditalic antpoltcondbolditalic antpoltcond-bolditalic.otf
antpoltconditalic     antpoltconditalic     antpoltcond-italic.otf
antpoltcondregular    antpoltcondregular    antpoltcond-regular.otf
antpoltexpdbold       antpoltexpdbold       antpoltexpd-bold.otf
```

You get three columns the second being the normalised (all lower-case, no
special characters, no spaces) name and the third being the file name (in lower-case).

You can run the list through `grep` or use the built-in mechanism to search
for particular fonts:

```
mtxrun --script fonts --list --pattern=deli* --all
```

gives

```
delicious             deliciousbold         Delicious-Bold.otf
deliciousbold         deliciousbold         Delicious-Bold.otf
deliciousbolditalic   deliciousbolditalic   Delicious-BoldItalic.otf
deliciousheavy        deliciousheavy        Delicious-Heavy.otf
deliciousitalic       deliciousitalic       Delicious-Italic.otf
deliciousmedium       deliciousitalic       Delicious-Italic.otf
deliciousnormal       deliciousroman        Delicious-Roman.otf
deliciousregular      deliciousheavy        Delicious-Heavy.otf
deliciousroman        deliciousroman        Delicious-Roman.otf
delicioussmallcaps    delicioussmallcaps    Delicious-SmallCaps.otf
```

### How do I select the font?

Since we deal just with one font without bold or italic font switches (however, the
selected font can of course be bold or italic) we can simply use `\definefont`:

```
\definefont [delicious] [name:deliciousroman]
```

This defines a macro `\delicious` which switches to the given font. The
`name:` prefix is used to refer to the normalised name in the font list
(second column). One can also use the `file:` prefix and use the file name
(third column) without the path.

### How do I restrict the scope of the font change?

You can use braces, `\start \stop`, `\begingroup \endgroup` or any other
grouping mechanism.

Here is a complete example which uses the font `Delicious-Roman` (an OpenType
font).

```
\definefont [delicious] [name:deliciousroman]

\starttext

\start
    \delicious
    \input knuth
\stop

\input knuth

\stoptext
```

The output:

[image: result]

The right box indicates that indeed the requested font is being used. Further
information can be found one the [ConTeXt wiki - Fonts in
LuaTeX](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Fonts_in_LuaTeX) and the
[Chapter on
fonts](http://context.aanhet.net/svn/contextman/context-reference/en/co-fonts.pdf).

Comment: If it's not in the list, it is not installed (at least not for ConTeXt). Are you sure you are using LuaTeX (MkIV) and you didn't forget to set `OSFONTDIR` or reloading the font database? For clarification of this very problem please contact the [mailing list](http://www.ntg.nl/mailman/listinfo/ntg-context)

Comment: `simplefonts` was superseded by [`\definefontfamily`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/definefontfamily).  There is also a new manual on [Fonts in MKIV](http://pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/fonts-mkiv.pdf).

Answer (score 10):

As far as delimiting small sections, you can use text property declarations. Fore example, to change the font to teletype and then back to default, follow this example:

```
\ttfamily http://www.ctan.org\normalfont
```

Or, use braces to restrict the scope of the change:

```
{\ttfamily http://www.ctan.org}
```

You could also create an environment with a declaration, for example when writing multiple lines of code:

```
\begin{ttfamily}
statement 1;
statement 2;
...
statement n;
\end{ttfamily}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer with a small working code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\myFont{Courier_New.ttf}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
Default \TeX\ font. {\myFont A unicode font.} Again default \TeX\ font.
\end{document}
```

Here, I have used the Courier new font. To check the available fonts, go to the directory: `/usr/share/fonts/`. Issueing the following command from here will give you a list of fonts available: `find . -type f -name "*.ttf`. You any of the font files here in place of `Courier_New.ttf` in line number 3.

Following is the output:
[image: Output of the sample code]

Comment: If you're using `fontspec` you shouldn't be using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. Don't load that package at all. And this answer doesn't really cover anything that the existing answers don't already cover.