# Moderncv change date font

Tags: fonts, moderncv

I would like to change the font of the date column if possible in moderncv. If that is not possible how do i change the font of the whole resume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it's possible. `moderncv` uses `\cventry` to typeset the information, so you can redefine this command (original definition in `moderncvbodyi.sty`) and add the required font modification for the date (the second argument). For example, to typeset the dates using the Zapf Chancery fonts in `\footnotesize` you would need

```
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{{\fontfamily{pzc}\footnotesize\selectfont#2}}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    .\strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{{\fontfamily{pzc}\footnotesize\selectfont#2}}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    .\strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}


\name{John}{Doe}

\begin{document}

\section{Education}
\cventry{1920--1950}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  \cventry{1920--1950}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description} 

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Gonzalo. Is there an easy way to just change the date font size?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the font of the date column in moderncv just like in any other case. You just have to adjust the `\date` line respectively. If you'd like to have a bold date you can use: `\date{\textbf{\today}}`. If you'd like to have another font it's getting a little more complicated, because font changes are always a little complicated in TeX. See for example here: [Change font in a single paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11539/change-font-in-a-single-paragraph) or here: [change font of certain part of the text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2053/change-font-of-certain-part-of-the-text)

Comment: I'm afraid this is not what the OP wants. He/she wants to change the font for the date column in cventries.